# Compiling with Mingw

Tags: c, mingw32

I have a bunch of C files and header files in the folder.  When I compile the C files with MinGW compiler, it shows that there is no such file or directory. But I have all the files in the same folder.  How do I get them to compile?

I have attached the code for your reference (file `computil.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <computil.h>
#include <dataio.h>

int getc_skip_marker_segment(const unsigned short marker, unsigned char **cbufptr, unsigned char *ebufptr)
{
  int ret;
  unsigned short length;

  ret = getc_ushort(&length, cbufptr, ebufptr);
  if(ret)return(ret);
  length -= 2;
  if(((*cbufptr)+length) >= ebufptr)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR : getc_skip_marker_segment : ");
    fprintf(stderr, "unexpected end of buffer when parsing ");
    fprintf(stderr, "marker %d segment of length %d\n", marker, length);
    return(-2); }(*cbufptr) += length; return(0);
  }
}
```

I am compiling it with `gcc -c computil.c`.

Comment: Try posting some code. May it helps. Also, put the full error message too.

Comment: When compiling the file, the error dislpays 
computil.c:18:22: fatal error: computil.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.But i am having the computil.h file in the same directory.

Comment: @Sathish Please edit your question and post the code in the question. Also post the command you are using to compile.

Comment: Note that if `computil.h` and `dataio.h` files are in the same directory, there is no reason to use `<>` instead of `""` check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are going to have to add the current directory to the list of "standard places" that gcc uses.  When you use  instead of "computil.h", a Unix-style compiler won't look in the current directory.

For a quick fix to that, add `-I.` to the gcc command line. (dash, capital eye, period):
    gcc -I. computil.c

If that's an application include file intended to be found where the source files are found, then you should change the include line to:
    #include "computil.h"

That's one of the valuable nuances from Classic C that got lost in the ANSI standardization process. Standard C lets the compiler decide if there's a difference or between <> bracketed and "" quoted headers.  It makes a difference in Unix and GNU ("GNU's Not Unix!"), well, pretty much is Unix only better in places.

Comment: Thank you Mike Housky! I have Stepped up, but there are some internal errors i will look over it.

Comment: We cant able to compile the file without main function?

Comment: Yes you need a `main` function, because that's the point where the program should start. If you don't have that, the compiler doesn't know what should happen if you start the program.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simple, `#include <header.h>` means "search in the compiler's own library directories, while `#include "header.h` means "search in the same directory as the .c file that made the #include".

I don't believe gcc has any library headers named computil.h and dataio.h, so the code won't compile.

Comment: Its not gcc header library, its user defined library

Comment: @Sathish Indeed. So why do you treat it as a gcc library header?

Comment: Ya, now i have mention it with "".